# Callback function clarification

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a javascript callback function setup like this

```
function myFunction(callback){

    $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
    //other code
    callback()
}

function otherFunction(){
   //some async operation
}

myFunction(otherFunction)
```

Does this code ensure that my `otherFunction` does not run before the viewport is changed and other code above it is implemented?

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous here, so yes `myFunction` should change the `meta` tag before the callback is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the code above the `callback` call is synchronous, then yes, `otherFunction` will run after all the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is best way to look into it. Here i have added a statement just before the `callBack function` . You can see the console log even after `otherfunction` execution. So it entirely depends upon whether you are using `synchronous` or `asynchronous` code before the function `invocation`.

```js
function myFunction(callback){

    $('#ipt').val(callback.name);
    //other code
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('hello')},5000)
    callback()
}

function otherFunction(){
   alert( $('#ipt').val());
}

myFunction(otherFunction)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ipt" placeholder="Dummy text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous callback functions will always run after all synchronous code has been completed. This is because JS has something called the event loop which looks the following way:

[image]

Whenever we do asynchronous operation often this is associated with a Web API. This web API is abstracted away from us. We don't need to know how the browser implements this feature (which probably is written in C++ as part of the browser). However, we are interested in the **value** of operation or eventual return value.

So what the browser does is whenever the webAPI's are finished the callback associated with  it is pushed in the **callback queue**. Then whenever the stack is empty the event loop will push an function on the stack.

This is why asynchronous operations will always be performed last, **because the event loop will wait for the stack to be empty before pushing an item on it.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it'll ensure that `myFunction` will run after all the code above it if and only if the code above `callback()` is also synchronous. In example it's ensured that `callback()` will only be executed once viewport has been changed.